# DynaTrace installation issue

Tags: performance, dynatrace

During re-installation of Dyntrace I getting below error, Tried to google it but didn't find any appropriate solution.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

When you say "re-installation" does it mean you hit the "Modify" option or did you install a 6.1 on an existing 6.0 installation?
Can you look at the Windows Event Log? Typically installers write error messages in the windows event log.

What I'Ve seen in the past is that some anti-virus software corrupated the msi file that people downloaded from our download servers. Can you try downloading it again? maybe from a different machien? You can get the current installers from here https://community.compuwareapm.com/community/display/EVAL/Step+1+-+Download+and+install+dynaTrace

Please also check out our community portal where we have a dedicated discussion forum for dynatrace related questions: https://community.compuwareapm.com/community/display/DTFORUM/dynaTrace+Forums+Home

Andi